# Zip with list output instead of tuple

Tags: python, list, zip

What is the fastest and most elegant way of doing list of lists from two lists?

I have

```
In [1]: a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

In [2]: b=[7,8,9,10,11,12]

In [3]: zip(a,b)
Out[3]: [(1, 7), (2, 8), (3, 9), (4, 10), (5, 11), (6, 12)]
```

And I'd like to have

```
In [3]: some_method(a,b)
Out[3]: [[1, 7], [2, 8], [3, 9], [4, 10], [5, 11], [6, 12]]
```

I was thinking about using map instead of zip, but I don't know if there is some standard library method to put as a first argument.

I can def my own function for this, and use map, my question is if there is already implemented something. **No** is also an answer.

Comment: Well, do you really **need** lists? What are you going to do with the results?

Comment: An example would be sklearn, where many times data must be organized in this fashion.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes he [/we]  *need* a list

Answer (score 137, accepted):

If you are zipping more than 2 lists (or even only 2, for that matter), a readable way would be:

```
[list(a) for a in zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9])]
```

This uses a list comprehension to [apply `list` to each element (tuple) in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082410), converting them into lists.

Answer (score 88):

You almost had the answer yourself. Don't use `map` instead of `zip`. Use `map` **AND** `zip`.

You can use map along with zip for an elegant, functional approach:

```
list(map(list, zip(a, b)))
```

`zip` returns a list of tuples. `map(list, [...])` calls `list` on each tuple in the list. `list(map([...])` turns the map object into a readable list.

Comment: the unfortunate decision to make python 3 collections operations return  a `generator` imposes the cost of the double `list` in here.

Comment: @WestCoastProjects: 1) It returns an iterator (generators are a specific type of iterator that enables coroutines) 2) That's not an unfortunate decision. In the majority of cases you want to iterate the result; making these functions produce a `list` of results eagerly means that you can't process the first result until you've processed *all* of them, you can't `break` the loop early and skip producing the rest of the results, and if the inputs are large but lazy themselves (e.g. file objects, `itertools` functions) you'll blow your RAM realizing all results when you don't need to.

Comment: Adding `list()` around `map` in the minority case is a small price to pay for the benefits realized all the times you don't need the wrapping (or when you do, but you don't want a plain unsorted `list`; `sorted(map(...))`, `set(map(...))`, etc. all involved a pointless temporary `list` in Py2 which Py3 avoids).

Answer (score 16):

I love the elegance of the zip function, but using the itemgetter() function in the operator module appears to be much faster.  I wrote a simple script to test this:

```
import time
from operator import itemgetter

list1 = list()
list2 = list()
origlist = list()
for i in range (1,5000000):
        t = (i, 2*i)
        origlist.append(t)

print "Using zip"
starttime = time.time()
list1, list2 = map(list, zip(*origlist))
elapsed = time.time()-starttime
print elapsed

print "Using itemgetter"
starttime = time.time()
list1 = map(itemgetter(0),origlist)
list2 = map(itemgetter(1),origlist)
elapsed = time.time()-starttime
print elapsed
```

I expected zip to be faster, but the itemgetter method wins by a long shot:

```
Using zip
6.1550450325
Using itemgetter
0.768098831177
```

Comment: This is a transpose of what the OP is trying to do. Could you update your post to reflect that? I.e., OP is converting two lists to list or arbitrary number of pairs. You are converting an arbitrary number of pairs to a pair of lists.

Comment: Which python version is this measured with?

Comment: I don't remember, it was over two years ago, but most likely 2.6 or 2.7.  I imagine you can copy the code and try it on your own version/platform.

Comment: python 2 `zip` creates a real list. That slows things down. Try replacing `zip` with `itertools.izip` then.

Comment: In Python 3.5, zip takes 3.5 seconds and itemgetter takes 0.10 seconds.
For those fond of list comprehensions, `list1 = [x[0] for x in origlist]` works just as well as `list1 = map(itemgetter(0), origlist)`.

Comment: @EliasStrehle: In Python 3.5, `map` is *lazy*; it didn't do any real work for case #2 (just created the `map` object w/o mapping anything from the inputs). If you make sure it produces a `list`, e.g. `list(map(itemgetter(0),origlist))`, and use a proper microbenchmarking method like the `timeit` module/IPython's `%timeit` magic, the times are much more similar. On 3.10, `%timeit list1, list2 = map(list, zip(*origlist))` is around 600 ms per loop, `%timeit list1, list2 = list(map(itemgetter(0), origlist)), list(map(itemgetter(1), origlist))` is ~575 ms. Faster, but irrelevantly so.

Answer (score 7):

How about this?

```
>>> def list_(*args): return list(args)

>>> map(list_, range(5), range(9,4,-1))
[[0, 9], [1, 8], [2, 7], [3, 6], [4, 5]]
```

Or even better:

```
>>> def zip_(*args): return map(list_, *args)
>>> zip_(range(5), range(9,4,-1))
[[0, 9], [1, 8], [2, 7], [3, 6], [4, 5]]
```

**Update for Python 3:**
In Python 3 map returns an iterator and not a list. This is the fastest from a few options I've tested (timed using the `timeit` module):

```
[list(t) for t in zip(*lists)]
```

**Update for 3.12**
The fastest way so far right now seems to be

```
[[*t] for t in zip(a, b)]
```

Comment: That seems to me a better answer than the rest as here we are reducing one step by not doing a zip and directly creating a list. Awesome

Answer (score 5):

I generally don't like using lambda, but...

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> c = lambda a, b: [list(c) for c in zip(a, b)]
>>> c(a, b)
[[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9], [5, 10]]
```

If you need the extra speed, map is slightly faster:

```
>>> d = lambda a, b: map(list, zip(a, b))
>>> d(a, b)
[[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9], [5, 10]]
```

However, map is considered unpythonic and should only be used for performance tuning.

Comment: What does `lambda` add here? One can just write the expression instead of calling a function (it's really not complicated), and even if one wants a function for it, it can be defined painlessly in two lines (one if your return key is broken or you're insane). `map` on the other hand is perfectly fine if the first argument would be a plain function (as opposed to a `lambda`).

Comment: Well he asked for a function. But I agree-- probably better just to pay the extra line. As for map, I believe list comprehensions are almost always clearer.

Comment: I would recommend `map` over `lambda`. so `map(list, zip(a,b))`. List comprehensions may be a little clearer, but map should be faster (untested)

Comment: I mean, again, if the OP needs speed, map is the way to go. But in general, and in Python especially, emphasize readability over speed (else you dip into premature optimization).

Answer (score 5):

List comprehension would be very simple  solution I guess.

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

b=[7,8,9,10,11,12]

x = [[i, j] for i, j in zip(a,b)]

print(x)

output : [[1, 7], [2, 8], [3, 9], [4, 10], [5, 11], [6, 12]]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Using numpy

The definition of elegance can be quite questionable but if you are working with `numpy` the creation of an array and its conversion to list (if needed...) could be very practical even though not so efficient compared to using the `map` function or the list comprehension.

```
import numpy as np 
a = b = range(10)
zipped = zip(a,b)
# result = np.array(zipped).tolist() Python 2.7
result = np.array(list(zipped)).tolist()
Out: [[0, 0],
 [1, 1],
 [2, 2],
 [3, 3],
 [4, 4],
 [5, 5],
 [6, 6],
 [7, 7],
 [8, 8],
 [9, 9]]
```

Otherwise skipping the `zip` function you can use directly [`np.dstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html#numpy.dstack):

```
np.dstack((a,b))[0].tolist()
```

Comment: The first example does not work for me, `np.array(zipped)` is a `array(<class 'zip'>, dtype=object)`, putting it into a list just return a `zip`

Comment: however `np.array(list(zipped)).tolist()` will work

Comment: @JeanBouvattier thanks for your comment, yes this is because in Python 3 zip is no more a list but a zip object