# Apply function to each element of a list

Tags: python, string, list, function, list-comprehension

Suppose I have a list like:

```py
mylis = ['this is test', 'another test']
```

How do I apply a function to each element in the list? For example, how do I apply `str.upper` to get:

```
['THIS IS TEST', 'ANOTHER TEST']
```

Comment: Although OP would not have had any idea about list comprehensions, I added the tag in the hope that it makes it easier for duplicate closers to find the question.

Comment: @shantanuo are you the one voting to close similar and older questions to your own? That would make this post the duplicate.

Comment: @EricHerlitz I closed many questions as a duplicate of this one because it was originally the best I could find for the purpose. However, I was still unsatified, and today after perhaps years of frustration I prepared a more useful canonical from scratch.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Using the built-in standard library [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> mylis = ['this is test', 'another test']
>>> list(map(str.upper, mylis))
['THIS IS TEST', 'ANOTHER TEST']
```

In Python 2.x, `map` constructed the desired new list by applying a given function to every element in a list.

In Python 3.x, `map` constructs an iterator instead of a list, so the call to `list` is necessary. If you are using Python 3.x and require a list the list comprehension approach would be better suited.

Answer (score 195):

Try using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> mylis = ['this is test', 'another test']
>>> [item.upper() for item in mylis]
['THIS IS TEST', 'ANOTHER TEST']
```

Comment: Personally I much prefer this. So Python.

Comment: wouldn't looping through a list be much slower?

Comment: If you want list as output then definitely this works better than anything

Comment: Something like that would be very convenient: mylist = mylist.apply(lambda x: x.upper()) ; F#-ish approach, very compact and easy to read; as far as I know there is no such structure now, but may be in the future Pythons?

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes you need to apply a function to the members of a list in place. The following code worked for me:

```
>>> def func(a, i):
...     a[i] = a[i].lower()
>>> a = ['TEST', 'TEXT']
>>> list(map(lambda i:func(a, i), range(0, len(a))))
[None, None]
>>> print(a)
['test', 'text']
```

Please note, the output of *map()* is passed to the *list* constructor to ensure the list is converted in Python 3. The returned list filled with *None* values should be ignored, since our purpose was to convert list *a* in place

Comment: A suggestion: don't create a list filled with `None`s only to throw it away immediately, use `any` instead of `list` around `map`. Also, use `range` with only one argument, the range will start from 0, same as list indices. Final result: `any(map(lambda i:func(a, i), range(len(a))))`. This expression will return `False` , but that can be ignored.

Comment: @ack Your suggestion is good where you care about the status of each element (e.g. you really do want to check if any of the results are not `None`) but not sure why else you would want to go to the trouble of looping through the `None`s to check them, only to throw away a different result? This is only an consideration when using the interpreter.

Comment: We could also use a generator expression instead of `map`. But really, rather than creating a mutating function that has to index back into the list, and providing it with the indices, it would be much cleaner to replace the list contents by slice assignment.

Answer (score 1):

String methods in Python are optimized, so you'll find that the loop implementations mentioned in the other answers here ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25082458/19123103), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25082439/19123103)) to be faster than vectorized methods in other libraries such as pandas and numpy that perform the same task.

In general, you can apply a function to every element in a list using a list comprehension or `map()` as mentioned in other answers here. For example, given an arbitrary function `func`, you can either do:

```py
new_list = [func(x) for x in mylis]
# or 
new_list = list(map(func, mylis))
```

If you want to **modify a list in-place**, you can replace every element by a slice assignment.

```py
# note that you don't need to cast `map` to a list for this assignment
# this is probably the fastest way to apply a function to a list 
mylis[:] = map(str.upper, mylis)
# or
mylis[:] = [x.upper() for x in mylis]
```

or with an explicit loop:

```py
for i in range(len(mylis)):
    mylis[i] = mylis[i].upper()
```

You can also check out the built-in [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) and [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) libraries for built-in methods to construct a function to apply to each element. For example, if you want to multiply each element in a list by 2, you can use `itertools.repeat` and `operator.mul`:

```py
from itertools import repeat, starmap
from operator import mul

newlis1 = list(map(mul, mylis, repeat(2)))
# or with starmap
newlis2 = list(starmap(mul, zip(mylis, repeat(2))))

# but at this point, list comprehension is simpler imo
newlis3 = [x*2 for x in mylis]
```