# How to remove specific substrings from a set of strings in Python?

Tags: python

I have a set of strings and all the strings have one of two specific substrings which I want to remove:

```
set1 = {'Apple.good', 'Orange.good', 'Pear.bad', 'Pear.good', 'Banana.bad', 'Potato.bad'}
```

I want the "`.good`" and "`.bad`" substrings removed from all the strings. I tried this:

```
for x in set1:
    x.replace('.good', '')
    x.replace('.bad', '')
```

but it doesn't seem to work, `set1` stays exactly the same. I tried using `for x in list(set1)` instead but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: I have plans to replace the canonical I have been using, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082410/apply-function-to-each-element-of-a-list, with a better, *more general* duplicate. The logic works the same way whether we call functions on the elements, call methods on the elements or use a simple expression to describe the new value; and it works essentially the same way if we iterate over any kind of iterable (and we can create multiple different kinds of results, depending on what kind of comprehension is used).

Comment: After several months, nothing better surfaced, so I implemented the aforementioned plan today.

Answer (score 328, accepted):

Strings are immutable. [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) creates a **new** string. This is stated in the documentation:

> `str.replace(old, new[, count])`
>
> Return a **copy** of the string with all occurrences of substring *old* replaced by *new*. [...]

This means you have to re-allocate the set or re-populate it (re-allocating is easier with a [set comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)):

```
new_set = {x.replace('.good', '').replace('.bad', '') for x in set1}
```

P.S. if you want to change the prefix or suffix of a string and you're using **Python 3.9** or newer, use [`str.removeprefix()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removeprefix) or [`str.removesuffix()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix) instead:

```
new_set = {x.removesuffix('.good').removesuffix('.bad') for x in set1}
```

Comment: Note: It also works with a list, simply use `[...]` instead of `{...}`

Comment: What's the point of editing this question to update it with `str.removesuffix()` for Python 3.9+ by copying the answer by @DineshKumar? It is fairer to let people credit the author of that answer.

Comment: @divenex I would edit back and link to dinesh's answer instead of copying it. I think its legit because it lives on the same page so its not like a link that can actually expire easily.

Comment: Please stop adding information from other answers here. Edits are to improve an answer, not to change it from its original meaning. Let the newer, better answer bubble up by upvoting it.

Answer (score 113):

```
>>> x = 'Pear.good'
>>> y = x.replace('.good','')
>>> y
'Pear'
>>> x
'Pear.good'
```

`.replace` doesn't *change* the string, it returns a copy of the string with the replacement. You can't change the string directly because strings are immutable.

You need to take the return values from `x.replace` and put them in a new set.

Comment: But when I loop over the set of strings, how can I update a new set? using set_name.update? Could you show that?

Answer (score 20):

In **Python 3.9**+ you could remove the suffix using `str.removesuffix('mysuffix')`. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix):

> If the string ends with the *suffix* string and that *suffix* is not empty, return `string[:-len(suffix)]`. Otherwise, return a copy of the original string

So you can either create a new empty set and add each element without the suffix to it:

```
set1  = {'Apple.good', 'Orange.good', 'Pear.bad', 'Pear.good', 'Banana.bad', 'Potato.bad'}

set2 = set()
for s in set1:
   set2.add(s.removesuffix(".good").removesuffix(".bad"))
```

Or create the new set using a set comprehension:

```
set2 = {s.removesuffix(".good").removesuffix(".bad") for s in set1}
   
print(set2)
```

Output:

```
{'Orange', 'Pear', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Potato'}
```

Answer (score 17):

All you need is a bit of black magic!

```
>>> a = ["cherry.bad","pear.good", "apple.good"]
>>> a = list(map(lambda x: x.replace('.good','').replace('.bad',''),a))
>>> a
['cherry', 'pear', 'apple']
```

Answer (score 11):

When there are multiple substrings to remove, one simple and effective option is to use `re.sub` with a compiled pattern that involves joining all the substrings-to-remove using the regex OR (`|`) pipe.

```
import re

to_remove = ['.good', '.bad']
strings = ['Apple.good','Orange.good','Pear.bad']

p = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, to_remove))) # escape to handle metachars
[p.sub('', s) for s in strings]
# ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear']
```

Answer (score 7):

```
# practices 2
str = "Amin Is A Good Programmer"
new_set = str.replace('Good', '')
print(new_set)

 

print : Amin Is A  Programmer
```

Comment: Hi Amin. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.

Comment: Hi, my friend, this code works with other long text. so even you can to get your string from the input and find text point ...

Comment: It is very bad practice to rename builtins like `str`.

Comment: that is not a set.

Comment: why that is not set but I know that is true. so what is your problem in this code.

Comment: I always try to choose the easiest ways but does this code have a problem? I saw it easily and shared it, but if there is a problem, tell me the reason.
Sincerely, Amin. -Elletlar

Answer (score 5):

You could do this:

```
import re
import string
set1={'Apple.good','Orange.good','Pear.bad','Pear.good','Banana.bad','Potato.bad'}

for x in set1:
    x.replace('.good',' ')
    x.replace('.bad',' ')
    x = re.sub('\.good$', '', x)
    x = re.sub('\.bad$', '', x)
    print(x)
```

Comment: line `x.replace('.good',' ')` and `x.replace('.bad',' ')` does not do anything to the final result. The print out will be the same without them.

Comment: Also I would rather have just one line with `re.sub`, like this: `x = re.sub('((\.good$)|(\.bad$))', '', x)`

Comment: @SrđanPopić yeah I agree with you

Comment: should we edit it accordingly? (remove `replace`s and move everything to one `re.sub` call)

Comment: @SrđanPopić I post this answer because it is simple and step wise.

Comment: in Python strings a immutable. `str.replace(old, new)` returns a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring 'old' replaced by 'new'. Its result must be assigned to a new variable. Just like it was explained in the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37372690/2690353

Answer (score 4):

I did the test (but it is not your example) and the data does not return them orderly or complete

```
>>> ind = ['p5','p1','p8','p4','p2','p8']
>>> newind = {x.replace('p','') for x in ind}
>>> newind
{'1', '2', '8', '5', '4'}
```

I proved that this works:

```
>>> ind = ['p5','p1','p8','p4','p2','p8']
>>> newind = [x.replace('p','') for x in ind]
>>> newind
['5', '1', '8', '4', '2', '8']
```

or

```
>>> newind = []
>>> ind = ['p5','p1','p8','p4','p2','p8']
>>> for x in ind:
...     newind.append(x.replace('p',''))
>>> newind
['5', '1', '8', '4', '2', '8']
```

Answer (score 0):

## If list

I was doing something for a list which is a set of strings and you want to remove all lines that have a certain substring you can do this

```
import re
def RemoveInList(sub,LinSplitUnOr):
    indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(LinSplitUnOr) if re.search(sub, x)]
    A = [i for j, i in enumerate(LinSplitUnOr) if j not in indices]
    return A
```

where `sub` is a patter that you do not wish to have in a list of lines `LinSplitUnOr`

for example

```
A=['Apple.good','Orange.good','Pear.bad','Pear.good','Banana.bad','Potato.bad']
sub = 'good'
A=RemoveInList(sub,A)
```

Then `A` will be

[image]

Comment: In Python, functions and variables are name `loweraces_with_underscores` not `CapitalCase`.