# Remove an element from a str

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list in which I add elements like this:

```
listA.append('{:<30s} {:>10s}'.format(element, str(code)))
```

so listA looks like this:

```
Paris          75
Amsterdam      120
New York City  444 
L.A            845
```

I would like, now from this listA, to add elements to a "listB" list, without the code. I would like to do this:

```
for i in listA:
    listB.append(i - str(code))   #that's what i want to do. The code is not good
```

and I want the listB to look like this:

```
    Paris
    Amsterdam 
    New York City
    L.A
```

and only using listA and without having access to 'element' and 'code'

Can someone can help me ?

Comment: Didn't quite understood, need clarification

Comment: You're not using `i` in the second loop at all. Where is `element` and `code` coming from?

Comment: It sounds like you're probably looking for this: [How to remove specific substrings...in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37372690)

Comment: Not sure I fully understand you, but why don't you build listB right after you build listA, something like - listB.append(element)?

Comment: @MilanCermak I change my post

Comment: @IftahP because it's just an example. in my project I no longer have access to 'element' and 'code'. I just have access to the list A already made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex for that

```
import re

for i in listA:
    listB.append(re.sub(r"\W+\d+", "", i))
```

This will remove the code that is numbers and the spaces before it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re
listB = [re.sub('\d+', '', x).strip() for x in listA]
print(listB)
```

**Output:**

```
['Paris', 'Amsterdam', 'New York City', 'L.A']
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me

```
listB=[]
for i in listA:
    listB.append(listA[0][:len(element)])
print(listB)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about to use `re.sub`? And instead of using `for in` it would be better to `map` functional style or `[for in]` list comprehension:

```
import re
listB = list(map(lambda x: re.sub(r"\s+\d+", "", x), listA))
```

or, even better

```
import re
listB = [re.sub(r"\s+\d+", "", x) for x in listA]
```

A little about regex:

- `re.sub` - is a function what searches an removes all occurrences of first argument to second in third one
- `r"\s+\d+"` - is a ['raw' string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) with regex inside
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces (`\t\n\r` etc)
- `\d+` - one or more digits (`\d` is an allias for `[0-9]`)
- For more information about regex use [this documentation page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way without any new libraries.

You can create a variable with 40 spaces(because of 40 spaces in the format clause). eg: `space_var = "    "`
Then use the following code to extract element from `listA`:

```
listB=[]
for i in listA:
    listB.append(listA[0].rsplit(space_var,1)[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```py
listB = [element.rsplit(' ', maxsplit=1)[0].rstrip() for element in listA]
```

`rsplit(' ', maxsplit=1)` means you will split the element of listA once at first space from the right side. Additional `rstrip()` will get rid of the other spaces from the right side.