# Python. how to convert the words inside two characters to a list

Tags: python

I want a way to create a list out of strings that appear in-between a
specific character, in this case **`** <-- that

so for example this string:

```
string = '<#346283347234774> **Useless text that I want to remove**
more useless text it is useless, so useless.
`potato`, `boxes`, `christmas tree`'
```

becomes this list

```
list = ['potato', 'boxes', 'christmas tree']
```

I've tried using regex but I would rather something readable to a total noob that i'll be able to understand when i come back to the code to update it at a later date.

Sorry if this is painfully simple, i'm really new to Python and programming in general.

Comment: This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372603/how-to-remove-specific-substrings-from-a-set-of-strings-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `re.findall`:

```
print(re.findall('`([\w+ ]*)`', string))
```

Output:

```
['potato', 'boxes', 'christmas tree']
```

**Explanation:**

In the above, I have :

```
`
```

On both sides of the expression. that just helps to try to match the group since you want the text between those two signs. Whatever is inside the parenthesis gets extracted by the `findall` function. In the parenthesis we have `\w+` which gets the characters inside the two signs, then we have an extra space so that it will also match the space between `'christmas tree'`, then the `*` matches everything.

Here is a [link](https://regex101.com/r/ymfSoE/2) for more explanation.

Comment: If you could please explain in brief what happens in the above ```findall()``` function that would be really helpful.

Comment: The `+` in the character group means you actually look for the literal `+` symbol. Slightly simpler and more efficient: `\`([^\`]*)\``

Comment: @Tomerikoo I edited it check it out.

Comment: You added an explanation... The `+` is still not necessary (unless you expect the `+` symbol as part of the words)

Comment: @Tomerikoo Anyway I kept it in there, also check my regex101 link

Comment: This worked, thanks! Its frustrating staring at regex101 explaining everything perfectly but still not understanding it though!

Comment: @Ben Haha, no problem