# How to exclude words from string

Tags: python

I'm using Python to get title names for a header in a program.
Each title comes like: "*OXD/Overview Controls*", "*OXD/BULK/BULK Details Controls*" and more...
Currently I am using a value/split() method to remove the "/" returning only "*OXD Overview Controls*" and "*OXD BULK*", however I would like to remove the "OXD" and "Controls" portions of the string. Any help is appreciated, my current code is listed below.

```
if value <> None:
    value = value.split("/")[:2]
    value = ' '.join(value)
else:
    value = ""  
return value.upper()
```

Comment: Here is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372603/how-to-remove-specific-substrings-from-a-set-of-strings-in-python

Comment: You could try slicing if it is always in the first 5 characters of the string. Or you could try the replace method. str.replace("thing to replace", "replace with this")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove specific substrings from a set of strings in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372603/how-to-remove-specific-substrings-from-a-set-of-strings-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

@Steven Barnard and @DSteman: Sorry, I wrote something and you both was faster as me. ^^'

You can use the `string_variable.replace(search,replace_with)` function.

Replace OXD with nothing:

```
value.replace("OXD","")
```

Replace / with Space:

```
value.replace("/"," ")
```