# Apply function to all items in a list

Tags: python, list, loops

I am trying to apply a function to a list. The function takes a value and produces another.

For example:

```
myCoolFunction(75)
```

would produce a new value.

So far I am using this:

```
x = 0
newValues = []

for value in my_list:
    x = x + 1
    newValues.append(myCoolFunction(value))
    print(x)
```

I am working with around 125,000 values and the speed at which this is operating does not seem very efficient.

Is there a more pythonic way to apply the function to the values?

Comment: A _list comprehension_: `new_values = [myCoolFunction(value) for value in my_list]`. Drop the camel-case on variable names too, it isn't part of [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply function to each element of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082410/apply-function-to-each-element-of-a-list)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) approach:

```
list(map(myCoolFunction, my_list))
```

This applies defined function on each value of `my_list` and creates a map object (3.x). Calling a `list()` on it creates a new list.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using pandas, here is how the pythonic mapping and list comprehension techniques mentioned above are done with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

def myCoolFunction(i):
    return i+1

my_list = [1,2,3]
df = pd.DataFrame(index=my_list, data=my_list, columns=['newValue']).apply(myCoolFunction)
```