# Write floats to a csv file to 2 significant figures

Tags: python, list, csv, floating-point, int

My writer function looks like:

```
with open(filename, "w") as file:
    file.truncate(0)
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerows(input_list)
```

My `input_list` looks like:

```
[[10.0, 11.0, 20.0, 20.0, 0.8], [40.0, 42.0, 20.0, 20.0, 0.6]]
```

My output csv file looks like:

```
10.0,11.0,20.0,20.0,0.8
40.0,42.0,20.0,20.0,0.6
```

I want it to look like:

```
10, 11, 20, 20, 0.8
40, 42, 20, 20, 0.6
```

I would like the formatting of the spaces after the numbers themselves. While I could add something within the program to create a space between the elements and check for whether the number is less than 1, before casting it to an `int` (numbers above 1 cannot be floats), I would like to look for a more pythonic and elegant solution.

Comment: “0.6” has only one significant digit as mathematicians define the term. What output do you want for 0, 123, and 0.123, or values like those never occur?

Comment: @EricPostpischil 0 and 123 can occur, but 0.123 can never occur. I would like to represent those two as 0 and 123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> from math import log10, floor
>>> def round_to_1(x):
...   return round(x, -int(floor(log10(abs(x)))))
```

Loop through your elements and apply this function before writing to a csv. Laborious but should work.

Comment: is there a way we can map this to each and every element within the list of lists, all in the same line as the line as the csv_writer? Maybe a map function?

Comment: Just use a double loop. For line in list: For item in line.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082410/apply-function-to-each-element-of-a-list

Answer (score -1):

You can use pandas library for this.

=^..^=

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[10.0, 11.0, 20.0, 20.0, 0.8], [40.0, 42.0, 20.0, 20.0, 0.6]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# convert values to int
df[0] = df[0].astype(int)
df[1] = df[1].astype(int)
df[2] = df[2].astype(int)
df[3] = df[3].astype(int)

# save data frame
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2   3    4
0  10  11  20  20  0.8
1  40  42  20  20  0.6
```

Comment: What about without pandas?

Comment: Using native Python tools?