# Lists and functions

Tags: python-3.x

Define a function that accepts a list (called numbers below) as input and return a list where each element is multiplied by 10. The grader will supply the argument numbers to the function when you run the grader.score.in__problem2 method below.

In this case, you need to write a function that will work for arbitrary input. Before submitting your function to the grader, you may want to check that it returns the output that you expect by evaluating code similar to the following:

```
test_numbers = [1, 2, 3]
mult(test_numbers)
```

I am relatively new to coding and i am finding it hard to come up with a proper solution

```
def mult(numbers):
    return (10) * len(numbers)
```

i expect output to be `(10, 20, 30)` but i only get 30 as a response

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply function to each element of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082410/apply-function-to-each-element-of-a-list)

Comment: `len(...)` returns the **len**gth of a list, which is why you are getting 30 (10 * 3)

Comment: okay that part i understand now, but i am struggling in finding a way to multiply the numbers in the array and returning it in the appropriate format and i have been at it for hours now

Comment: @BrianDemadema look at using [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)

Comment: Thank you, will have a look at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
def mult(my_list):
    return [10*n for n in my_list]
```

```
>>> m = [1,2,3]
>>> mult(m)

[10,20,30]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in function called [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) that does this.

> Return an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable, yielding the results.

As example for what you want to do:

```
test_numbers = [1, 2, 3]
print(list(map(lambda x: x*10, test_numbers)))
# [10, 20, 30]
```

If you need to code it yourself you need to iterate over your list. For that we use the keyword `for`.

```
new_list = []
test_numbers = [1, 2, 3]
for number in test_numbers:
    new_list.append(number * 10)
print(new_list)
# [10, 20, 30]
```

For each iteration, `number` is evaluating to each item in the list (first iteration is 1, second is 2, third is 3).

Answer (score 0):

You can use for to iterate over your array list:

```
test_numbers=[1,2,3]
for var in test_numbers:
  print (##test_numbers.index(var),
         var*10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write as follows:

```
def multiply(numbers):
    return [item*10 for item in numbers]

numbers= [1, 2, 3]
multiply(numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_numbers=[]
def mult(numbers):
    for number in numbers:
        new_number = number*10
        new_numbers.append(new_number)
    return new_numbers
```