# Build a string with a deque of integer displayed as hexadecimal

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-collections

I have a deque full of integer and I would like to build a string (or just print it) in hexadecimal format.

I tried

```py
from collections import deque

a = deque([10,11])
my_string = hex(a)
```

It says that deque can't be interpreted as an integer. I would like something like :

```
deque([0xA, 0xB])
```

Comment: so `deque(map(hex, a))`? Your desired output is invalid (missing the quotes).

Comment: Why do you not build the string then? Copy the deque into a list, build a list of its hex representations and print it...

Comment: @pault: You should give that as an answer. Perhaps include converting your answer to a string and removing all the single quotes, to completely match the OP's format--I do see some possible uses for that format.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I don't know - should it be closed as a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973766/understanding-the-map-function) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082410/apply-function-to-each-element-of-a-list) instead?

Comment: @pault: I don't think so, since those other questions are much more general. This question does not mention `map` at all.

Comment: @RoryDaulton moot point anyway since OP answered their own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pault comment's answer :

```
    >>> deque(map(hex, a))
deque(['0xa', '0xb'])
```