# How to perform a method on a string in list in a list in Python

Tags: python, string, list

I would appreciate some help. I have a list of lists. The list containing all lists is called all_lists. In the lists of all_lists are strings. I want to apply a method on the text of each string in each list.

```
list_in_list = all_lists[0] #prints first list
string_in_list = list_in_list[0] #prints string in first list
```

I want to create a for loop which will allow me to alter all the strings with a method, and put them back in lists, and puts all lists back in the all_lists. This is what I have for now:

```
new_list = []
for i in range(len(all_lists)): # all lists
    list_in_list = all_lists[i] # separate lists from all_lists
    for j in range(len(list_in_list)): # every list in all_list
        string_in_list = line[j] # separate string from list
        new_string = decontracted(string_in_list) # apply the method on string
        new_list.append(new_string) # put new string back in a list
```

I am unsure how to put every list back in a list containing all lists. Can anyone help me do this?

Example if the method was to capitalize every string:

from:

```
[['list one'],['list two'],['list...'],['list n']]
```

to:

```
[['LIST ONE'],['LIST TWO'],['LIST...'],['LIST N']]
```

Comment: Is there a reason your inner lists have only one item?

Comment: Yes,  I am preprocessing text for a classifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `for loops` or `list comprehension` to achieve the result in your example.

```
all_lists = [['list one'],['list two'],['list...'],['list n']]
```

As a function, we can perform the `upper` for every element in the list, using a `for loop`.

```
def upper_list(data):
    result = []
    for nested in data:
        changes = []
        for element in nested:
            changes.append(element.upper())
        result.append(changes)
    return result

upper_list(all_lists)
#[['LIST ONE'], ['LIST TWO'], ['LIST...'], ['LIST N']]
```

Furthermore you can use list comprehension to compress the above into a single line of code.

```
all_lists = [[element.upper() for element in nested] for nested in all_lists]
```

Both of these would work over nested lists including multiple elements such as;

```
all_lists = [['list one', 'test'],['list two','two'],['list...'],['list n']]

>>>[[element.upper() for element in nested] for nested in all_lists]
#[['LIST ONE', 'TEST'], ['LIST TWO', 'TWO'], ['LIST...'], ['LIST N']]
```

Comment: Thank you! your upper_list function worked, as my goal was to apply another method. The capitalizing was just an example :)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply function to each element of list using `map`:

```
list(map(lambda x: [x[0].upper()], lst))
```

**Code**:

```
lst = [['list one'],['list two'],['list...'],['list n']]

print(list(map(lambda x: [x[0].upper()], lst)))
# [['LIST ONE'], ['LIST TWO'], ['LIST...'], ['LIST N']]
```

This is not limited; we can apply any custom function to transform elements in list, on your example:

```
list(map(decontracted, lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

A functional approach using map and filter would be a useful way.  See a similar question below:
[Apply function to each element of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082410/apply-function-to-each-element-of-a-list)

Comment: Thanks a lot, map didn't work for me though, since I was trying to apply a method I had previously created. The capitalizing was just an example. The method of  PacketLoss worked though, so it's solved!