# How to solve this error from this python code? (((unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int')))

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, python-3.8

I have some code like:

```
a=int(input("Add a:"))
b=int(input("Add b:"))
c=int(input("Add c:"))
d=int(input("Add d:"))
r_list=[a,b,c,d]

for i in r_list:
    y= r_list-2
    print (y)
```

How can I subtract 2 from each element of the list using a function?

Comment: you should probably do something like this  `y= r_list[i]-2`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply function to each element of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082410/apply-function-to-each-element-of-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most Pythonistic approach would be using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

`decreased_r_list = [x - 2 for x in r_list]`

You could also extract the transformation into a function (which for this simple example would be an overkill):

```
def minus_two(num):
    return num - 2

decreased_r_list = [minus_two(x) for x in r_list]
```

This will return a new list containing the transformed elements.
Generally, flat is better than nested, so the more you use list comprehension and a more functional-programming approach, the better.

Comment: If you run `import dis; dis.dis('[x - 2 for x in r_list]')`, you'll see (at least in CPython), that the list comp even does create and use a function :-P

Comment: That's very cool - thanks for sharing! I meant that the operation itself is an explicit function from the coder's perspective, which makes the code more modular and also enable much more advanced logic.

Comment: Yeah yeah, of course. But if it were *my* homework, I'd totally submit a list comp and argue like that :-D. And now I wonder *why* it does that. Presumably to get its own scope or so, so that its variables don't leak outside. Just tried it in Python 2 as well, because that does leak, and there it doesn't create a function.

Comment: [Looks like](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/711381dfb09fbd434cc3b404656f7fd306161a64/Python/compile.c#L4342-L4344) that's indeed the reason.

Answer (score 1):

You’re currently subtracting 2 from the list itself. To instead use the current element (which you called `i`) you can use `y = i - 2`