# changing () to [] in a Python Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a way to make a Python dictionary that encloses the lists of values in [] rather than().

```
keys = ["field1", "field2", "field3"]
values = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [6,7,8]]
dictionary = dict(zip(keys, zip(*values)))
```

gives:

{'field2': (2, 4, 7), 'field1': (1, 3, 6), 'field3': (3, 5, 8)}

What I want is:

{'field2': [2, 4, 7], 'field1': [1, 3, 6], 'field3': [3, 5, 8]}

Thank you!

Comment: `list(zip(*values))`

Comment: `dict(zip(keys, [list(z) for z in zip(*values)]))`

Comment: I think dictionary = dict(zip(keys, values)) does it

Comment: Not sure that was a good candidate for the dup - this one feels like a better a fit [Zip with list output instead of tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8372399/771848).