# Include For loop inside function for processing list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function to process the list of tuples. What is the easiest way to include `for` loop inside the function itself? I am fairly new to python, trying to convert this in OOP function. Any help will be appreciated.

My current solution:

```
tups = [(1,a),(2,b),(5,t)]

def func(a,b):
    # do something for a and b
    return (c,d)

output = []
for x, y in tups:
    output.append(func(x,y))
```

output will be

```
[(c,d),(m,n),(h,j)]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372399/zip-with-list-output-instead-of-tuple https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867882/tuple-unpacking-in-for-loops

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? _What is the easiest way to include for loop inside the function itself?_ Are you asking how to write a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `map` is more suitable for your use case

```
tups = [(1,"a"),(2,"b"),(5,"t")]

def func(z):
    # some random operation say interchanging elements
    x, y = z
    return y, x

tups_new = list(map(func, tups))
print(tups_new)
```

Output:

```
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('t', 5)]
```

Comment: This was quick and easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

just write your loop in `func`:

```py
tups = [(1,a),(2,b),(5,t)]

def func(tuples):
    for a, b in tuples:
        # do something for a and b
        result.append((c,d))
    return result

output = []
output.append(func(tups))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this with list comprehensions:

```
tups = [(1,"a"),(2,"b"),(5,"t")]

print([(obj[1], obj[0]) for obj in tups])

# [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('t', 5)]
```