# How to merge values of two arrays into one?

Tags: python, arraylist

How to merge two arrays as value-pairs in python?
Example as follows:

```
A = [0,2,2,3]
B = [1,1,4,4]
```

Output:

```
[[0,1],[2,1],[2,4],[3,4]]
```

Comment: You'll need to write code, which you do not appear to have even attempted to do.

Comment: Look into the zip builtin function: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: `Output` is not key/value. It is a list of lists

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use "zip"

```
l1 = [0,2,2,3]
l2 = [1,1,4,4]
print(list(map(list ,zip(l1,l2))))
```

Comment: This will give you `[[0, 1], [2, 1], [2, 4], [3, 4]]`. There are no key-value here.

Comment: but he asked this to be the output Ahmet Burak already commented on this

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Greg's answer, if you need key value pairs cast your zip result to dict

```
l1 = [0,2,2,3]
l2 = [1,1,4,4]
print(dict(zip(l1,l2)))
```

Output

```
{0: 1, 2: 4, 3: 4}
```

Before creating any loop, try to use built-ins.

Also there is a similar question for your need
[Zip with list output instead of tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372399/zip-with-list-output-instead-of-tuple)

Answer (score 0):

You can simultaniously itterate through using `zip()`, and append a result list with each of the pairs like so:

```py
A = [0,2,2,3]

B = [1,1,4,4]

result = []
for item1, item2 in zip(A,B):
    result.append([item1, item2])


Output = [[0,1],[2,1],[2,4],[3,4]]

print(result) # Prints: [[0,1],[2,1],[2,4],[3,4]]
print(Output == result) # Prints: True
```

This would give you a list of lists like you were looking for in your question as an output.

### Things to keep in mind

If the two starting lists are different sizes then `zip()` throws away values after one of the lists runs out, so with :

```py
A = [0,2,2,3,4,5]

B = [1,1,4,4]

result = []
for item1, item2 in zip(A,B):
    result.append([item1, item2])


Output = [[0,1],[2,1],[2,4],[3,4]]

print(result) # Prints: [[0,1],[2,1],[2,4],[3,4]]
print(Output == result) # Prints: True
```

You notice that the 4 and 5 in list `A` is thrown out and ignored.

### Key-Value Pair

Also this is not a key-value pair, for that you will want to look into [dictionaries in python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp). That would be something like:

```py
output = {0:1, 2:4, 3:4}
```

This would allow you to do a lookup for a value, based on it's key like so:

```py
output[3] # Would be 4
output[0] # Would be 1
```

Which doesn't work for this example because there are two 2's used as keys, so one would be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned key-value, you probably mean a dictionary.

```
A = [0, 2, 2, 3]
B = [1, 1, 4, 4]

dct = {} # Empty dictionary

for key, value in zip(A, B):
    dct[key] = value

print(dct)
```

The output will be:

```
{0: 1, 2: 4, 3: 4}
```

Note that, by definition, you can't have two identical keys. So in your case, `{2: 1}` will be overriden by `{2: 4}`.