# why doesn't this jms expression work in conjuction with range()

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Basically I want to filter a nested array of that shape:

```
[
  [0, {…}],
  [1, {…}],
  …
]
```

this jms path expression is working on the playground:

```
[?@[0] > `0`]
```

and when run like that from an ansible playbook:

```
- debug: msg="{{ [[1],[2],[3],[4]] | community.general.json_query('[?@[0] > `1`]') }}"
```

but when done like that:

```
- debug: msg="{{ range(0,3) | zip(range(3,0,-1)) | community.general.json_query('[?@[0] > `1`]') }}"
```

it yields an empty list (`[]`)

Boiling it down even more:

```
ansible@r2d2:~$ ansible localhost -m debug -a $'msg="{{ range(0, 3) | zip(range(3,0,-1)) | json_query(\'@[0]\')  }}"'
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "(0, 3)"
}
```

Show that the result is some sort of tuple, which is no json data type at all. The data that I would like to filter is constructed like the above, using `range` and `zip` so how can make the expression work in those circumstances?

**UPDATE**

Going deeper on that showed that this whole problem has two causes.

1. `{{ range(0,3) | type_debug }} => 'range'` can easily be solved by `{{ range(0,3) | list | … }}`
2. `{{ [0] | list | zip([0]) | list | json_query('@[0]') | type_debug }}` => 'tuple'

There seams to be a python solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372399/zip-with-list-output-instead-of-tuple), but how to do that in jinja??

Answer (score 0):

Finally. This code is working. Thanks to

```
[…] | zip([…]) | map('list')
```

that turn all tuple items into lists which work with `json_query` (jmspath).

```
- debug: msg="{{ indexed | community.general.json_query(q) }}"
  vars:
    # using this way to write the query resolves a lot quoting issues
    q: >-
      [?@[0] > `0`]
    keys: "{{ range(0, 3) }}"
    # map('list') is the magic sauce here
    indexed: "{{ keys | zip([3,2,1]) | map('list') }}"
```